# Postgres | How the get rows according to the exact or less IP list and a simple Text list

Tags: sql, postgresql, ip, subnet

I have a table that holds 2 text columns: type and IP.
Both of them can be a single text or a multiple text separated with '@##@'.
in addition, the ip can also be a range such as 1.1.1.1/24

the table below

```
row |type       | ip
-------------------------------------------
1   |red           | 1.1.1.1
2.  |red@##@blue   | 1.1.1.1@##@2.2.2.2
3.  |blue          | 1.1.1.1/32@##@2.2.2.2/32
4.  |yellow        | 1.1.1.1
5.  |red           | 3.3.3.3
6.  |yellow@##@red | 1.1.1.1
7.  |blue          | 1.1.1.1@##@3.3.3.3
```

I want to get all the rows that have
type red or blue or both (exactly red and blue or less, meaning a single red or a single blue)
AND
IP 1.1.1.1 or 2.2.2.2 or both including ranges (exactly 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 or less meaning a single 1.1.1.1 or a single 2.2.2.2 or if we have multiple ips, they need to match the range ecactly or less)

meaning I want to get rows 1,2,3

I started to write the next query but I can't get it right:

```
    SELECT * FROM t where
    regexp_split_to_array(t.type, '@##@')::text[] in ('red','blue')
    and
    regexp_split_to_array(t.ip, '@##@')::inet[] in ('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You want the overlaps operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE regexp_split_to_array(t.type, '@##@')::text[] && array['red', 'blue'] and
      regexp_split_to_array(t.ip, '@##@')::inet[] && array['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching `type` so that one, the other, or both match can be accomplished with the containment operator since the underlying comparison is equality.

Matching `inet` types to subnets is a different story.  That has to use the `inet` `&&` operator (contains or is contained by), so the `ip` array has to be turned to rows by `unnest`.  The requirement to again match one, the other, or both means we need a count of `ip` values and return rows only where the count of matches equals the count of `ip` values.

This query appears to do the job.  [Fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nBGYVNCkiv2MV2F1QbuedC/0)

```
with asarrays as (
  SELECT row, regexp_split_to_array(t.type, '@##@')::text[] as types,
         unnest(regexp_split_to_array(t.ip, '@##@')::inet[]) as ip
    FROM t
), typematch as (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by row) as totcount
    from asarrays 
   where types <@ array['red', 'blue']
), ipmatch as (  
  select *, count(*) over (partition by row) as matchcount
    from typematch
   where ip && any(array['1.1.1.1'::inet, '2.2.2.2'::inet])
)
select row, types, array_agg(ip) as ip 
  from ipmatch
 where matchcount = totcount
 group by row, types;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Im missing one thing. lets say  i have a row in the table that the ip is set to 1.1.1.1/30 which means 1.1.1.0-1.1.1.4. I want to get this row only if the "where" under ipmatch contains  the whole range or more, meaning  where ip && any(array['1.1.1.0'::inet,'1.1.1.1'::inet,'1.1.1.2'::inet,'1.1.1.3'::inet,'1.1.1.4'::inet],'1.1.1.5'::inet]) will get me the row but    where ip && any(array['1.1.1.0'::inet, '1.1.1.1'::inet]) will not get me the row. is this possible ?

Comment: @TalLevi  That is very different from your original question.  Can you please update your question and sample data to illustrate what you are looking for?

Comment: I open a different question regarding the ip-subnet issue only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270241/postgress-sql-get-a-row-only-if-the-subnet-is-part-of-a-given-ip-list