# Postgress | SQL | Get a row only if the subnet is part of a given ip list

Tags: sql, postgresql, ip, subnet

I have a table with text column that holds ip with subnet

```
| ip
-------------
| 1.1.1.1/30
```

when you convert 1.1.1.1/30 to list of ip you get:

```
1.1.1.0
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
```

I want to run a sql on this table and give a list of ips somehow as part of "where" or anything else, and get this row only if the list of the ips that I give contain the ips of the range in the row.

meaning,

```
where ('1.1.1.0','1.1.1.1)
```

--> I will not get the row

but:

```
where ('1.1.1.0','1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2,1.1.1.3)
```

--> I will get the row

but:

```
where ('1.1.1.0','1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2,1.1.1.3,1.1.1.4,1.1.1.5)
```

--> I will get the row

Is there anyway to do that ?

Comment: Note the /30 can be converted to a bit mask that can be bit-wise AND'd with an IP address in binary form to strip away the bits that don't matter. Compare two IP addresses that have been AND'd with the mask and they will be equal if they are both in the network specified.

Answer (score 1):

You have to expand out the `inet` into all its `host` values and then use containment to accomplish this:

```
with blowout as (
  select t.ip, array_agg(host(network(t.ip::inet) + gs.n)) as all_ips
    from t
   cross join lateral 
         generate_series(0, broadcast(t.ip::inet) - network(t.ip::inet)) as gs(n)
   group by t.ip;
)
select *
  from blowout
 where all_ips <@ array['1.1.1.0', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', 
                        '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.4', '1.1.1.5']::text[] 
;
```

Since you are not using any special `inet` functions in the comparison, it is best to do the comparisons using `text`.